# AngularJS: Using a directive result in ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to be able to define a section of my web page to only be viewable depending on the result of a directive (which will only be returning true or false).

```
<div ng-show="?">... /<div>
```

.

```
//Determines if anything is being loaded
app.directive('isloading', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                if ($http.pendingRequests.length > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I know this can be done by using a separate service, but is there a straightforward way i can do it like this?

**UPDATE**

Managed to achieve this by basically creating my own ng-show directive for when something is loading. I'm sure it can be refined more, but this is my current solution -

```
app.directive('isloading', function ($http) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                if ($http.pendingRequests.length > 0) {
                    element.css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    element.css('display', '');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You can create isLoading directive and use it *instead of* ngShow.

Comment: there is no point in creating a directive to do that. You must eitheir use the ng-show and use/put isLoading into a service OR you must define a new directive mimicking ng-show.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't consider making my own ng-show type directive. But I did get it working. I'll update my answer with the solution.